# Vertically align Pressable inside a Text component

Tags: react-native

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
  }}
>
  <Text
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    By continuing, you agree to our{" "}
    <Pressable
      onPress={...}
    >
      <Text>
        Terms of Service
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  </Text>
</View>
```

"Terms of Service" is printed higher than "By continuing, you agree to our". How do I vertically align them?
Or more precisely - how do I get the `Pressable` Text to vertically align to the bottom?
[image]

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Antoni see my answer below for a workaround I did. However, there are other great answers below that are probably better. It was not a serious problem and I was able to handle it, so I never dug deep into it.

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug in React Native itself. There are several open reports of this bug on React Native's GitHub, but the chances of it being fixed don't look good:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30375 - for the general problem of `View`s nested in `Text` being mis-aligned on Android, and a core contributor responded, but appeared to get derailed and stuck in some details specific to mimicking superscript and subscript.
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31955 - specific to `Pressable` and someone posted a PR to fix it, but Facebook closed it because no-one from Facebook got around to reviewing it before it became stale and out of date with the main branch.
- There's also some discussion in [this issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23601#issuecomment-468069822), but the issue got closed.

---

In [React Native >= 0.65](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#added-11), if your inline pressable element uses only text styles, you can work around this issue by using `<Text>` with `onPress` (and `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` to style the pressed state). Crude example:

```js
/**
 * Like a simplified Pressable that doesn't look broken inline in `Text` on Android
 */ 
const TextButton = ({ children, onPress, style, ...rest } => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false)
  const onPressIn = () => setPressed(true)
  const onPressOut = () => setPressed(false)
  return (
    <Text
      onPress={onPress}
      onPressIn={onPressIn}
      onPressOut={onPressOut}
      style={typeof style === 'function' ? style({ pressed }) : style}
      {...rest}
    >
      {typeof children === 'function' ? children({ pressed }) : children}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Beware, however, that there are also [bugs around selecting interactive elements nested inside text using accessibility tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32004). If you can simply avoid nesting the interactive element in text, and have it on its own line, that's probably better: link-like interactive nested text isn't well supported in React Native currently.

---

On older versions of React Native before 0.65, Text didn't support `onPressIn` or `onPressOut`:

- If you don't need `Pressable`'s `pressed` state, use `Text` instead of `Pressable` (as the asker did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590787/568458)
- If you *do* need pressed state, `Text` doesn't support the required `onPressIn/Out` handlers. However, `TouchableWithoutFeedback` does support those, and works by injecting props into its child so the `Text` will remain `Text` with no wrapping `View`. Wrap a `Text` in `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and pass the touchable `onPress` with `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` handlers and store the pressed state yourself.

```js
/**
 * Like a simplified Pressable that doesn't look broken inline in `Text` on Android
 */ 
const TextButton = ({ children, onPress, style, ...rest } => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false)
  const onPressIn = () => setPressed(true)
  const onPressOut = () => setPressed(false)

  // TouchableWithoutFeedback modifies and returns its child; this returns `Text`
  // plus press in/out events attached that aren't supported by Text directly.
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={onPress}
      onPressIn={onPressIn}
      onPressOut={onPressOut}
    >
      <Text
        style={typeof style === 'function' ? style({ pressed }) : style}
        {...rest}
      >
        {typeof children === 'function' ? children({ pressed }) : children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

Warning: if you're also using **React Native Web** and **React Navigation**, don't use the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` approach on Web, use pure `Pressable` on web, because React Navigation's navigate functions don't reliably work when passed to `Touchable*`s on Web due to a quirk of how the event handlers are set up (but they do work in Pressable), and this issue doesn't exist on Web.

Comment: since the 0.66 version, the Text component includes the onPressIn/Out handlers so a workaround would be to use the Text or the TouchableWithoutFeedback component

Answer (score 2):

Ended up doing this differently, using the `onPress` property of the `<Text>` component and finally wrapping all `<Text>` components in another `<Text>` component to have a proper line break:

```
<View>
  <Text>
    <Text>
      By continuing, you agree to our{" "}
    </Text>
    <Text onPress={() => {...}}>
      Terms of Service
    </Text>
    <Text>
      {" "}and our{" "}
    </Text>
    <Text onPress={() => {...}}>
      Privacy Policy
    </Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: This is hard to hit. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below should work but hard to understand without giving a shot. If you can provide screenshots I can help more in sake of getting a more proper result.

```html
<View>
  <Text style={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }}>
    By continuing, you agree to our{" "}
    <Pressable
      onPress={() => {
        navigate("LegalStack", { screen: "Terms" });
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{margin: 'auto'}}>
        Terms of Service
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Tried but same result. Added screenshot

Comment: And I also edited it. Please give it a chance also since I just realized the situation when I saw the text

Comment: and then I'd try adding **`style={{margin: 'auto'}}`** into the **`<Text>`** tag which contains the **`Terms of Service`** content as I edited the snippet above both the flex styles within outer text tag applied or not (:.

Comment: As a last chance I'd try the same line with **`style={{margin: '0px auto'}}`**. It's easier to debug on devTools like livecoding but remoteGuessing is a bit harsh though.

Comment: Thanks for trying. `'0px auto'` is not a valid RN style syntax. You are right, debugging this without seeing it is tough.. If I find a solution I will update.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very hackidy-hack solution...

```js
<Text selectable={true}>
     <Text>if you click</Text>
     <TouchableOpacity
       style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
       onPress={() => Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com")}
     >
         <Text
           style={{
             alignSelf: 'flex-end',
             marginBottom: -4,
           }}
         >
             here
         </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <Text>, it will open google</Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

A crazy trick that I just did (and if you are not using translations), I used the text as an SVG component that I exported from Figma.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `flexDirection` is column. Change it to `flexDirection:"row"`